# How do I schedule a linux backup job on a machine that's not always on?

Tags: linux, backup, systemd, administration, incremental-backup

I'd like to backup my files at midnight every day. Sometimes, I don't leave my computer on all night, and sometimes I don't use it for 2 or 3 days. When I turn my machine on, I want it to immediately run the job if it missed the backup scheduled. If I don't turn on my machine all week, I only still want it to run the backup once.

Is this possible? Can anacron, systemd, or another common linux tool be configured to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with systemd's option `Persistent=true`. [Example](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd/Timers#Realtime_timer)